# iptables : what is wrong with this iptables rule?

Tags: iptables

I am running this command :

> iptables -A http_flood -m hashlimit --hashlimit 1/sec --hashlimit-burst 3 --hashlimit-mode dstip,dstport,srcport --hashlimit-name hosts -j MARK --set-mark 0xf100

And getting this error:

> iptables: Unknown error 4294967295

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from man page of iptables:

> MARK
>          This  is  used  to  set the netfilter mark value associated with the packet.  It is only valid in the mangle table.  It can for example be used in conjunction with iproute2.